# System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'x' from assembly 'y'

Tags: c#, exception, struct, vb6-migration

I am trying to port a program from VB6 to C# that reads in a binary file and parses it. I get no compile time errors or warnings however when I try to run it, before it even enters `Main()` it throws the exception

```
System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
  Message=Could not load type 'Conversion.DataStructures.ClientOld' from assembly
     'SandboxConsole, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because
     it contains an object field at offset 1 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped
     by a non-object field.
  Source=SandboxConsole
  TypeName=Conversion.DataStructures.ClientOld
  StackTrace:
       at sandbox.Program.Main(String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Here is a sample of the old VB6 code

```
Private Type SrcClientOld
    Active As String * 1            '0
    titleLength As Byte             '1
    title As String * 8             '2
    lastNameLength As Byte          '10
    LastName As String * 25         '11
    (...)
    AddedBy As String * 3           '369
    junk7 As String * 22            '372
End Type                            '394
```

And here is my C# code I wrote

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
struct ClientOld
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Active;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    public string Title;

    [FieldOffset(10)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    public string LastName;

    (...)

    [FieldOffset(368)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    public string AddedBy;

    [FieldOffset(372)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 22)]
    public byte[] Unknown7;
}
```

After some googleing I thought that it was that I was missing the `Pack = 1` but adding that did not solve my issue.

Any other suggestions on what to do?

**EDIT:**

The first charater is one byte long, here is a hex dump of the first record in the file

```
A.Dr.......Smith....................
41 03 44 72 2E 00 00 00 00 00 05 53 6D 69 74 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
|  |  |                       |  ^LastName
|  |  ^title                  ^lastNameLength
|  ^titleLength
^Active
```

**EDIT2:**
Changing my code to the following to strip out all other possible errors it is still giving me the same exception

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)]
struct ClientOld
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte Active;

    [FieldOffset(1)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]
    public string Title;
}
```

I tried both fieldoffset(1) and 2 and neither work.

Comment: Can you post the VB6 Len(SrcClientOld) of the struct? Possibly with only the first two members?

Comment: @Marino Šimić Len returns 394 for the entire structure for every record. In the VB6 code it would record the entire fixed width block for the record and then when it was actually pulling data from the struct it would do something like `Left(recClient.LastName, recClient.lastNameLength)`

Comment: Hmm, why are you declaring what used to be a `String` type as a `byte` now? Specifically, the first member of the structure, `Active`.

Comment: @Cody Gray If you look at the data structure Active is a one byte charator. In VB6 you can just use a string array to read it, but in C# you need to convert it to a byte.

Comment: I looked at the data structure... The problem is, a `byte` is **not** equivalent to a single character. You're getting your data types mixed up. You can't convert strings (or individual characters within) to a `byte`. You need to declare it either as a `char` or a `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

Active As String * 1

translates to

Char

which in a Unicode language is not 1 byte, so the next field offset should not be 1, but probably 7 if I understood the following correctly:.

Explanation:

Here is the key to understanding strings: when we write the code:

> Dim str As String str = "help" we are
>   not defining a Unicode character array
>   per se. We are defining a member of a
>   data type called BSTR, which is short
>   for Basic String. A BSTR is, in fact,
>   a pointer to a null-terminated Unicode
>   character array that is preceeded by a
>   4-byte length field.

Edit:

By your dump it seems that the second member should have [FieldOffset(2)] because if not it would overlap on the previous member. (edit false alarm, I have seen a 00 where there is a 03).

Comment: Yes it should, I have, updated my question to include a example of the first part of the first record.

Comment: So the field offset is set by the start of the string, not the start of the string length? What would happen if I had a string as my first element, would i use offset (1) for it?

Comment: sorry i have seen a 00 where there is a 03, bad eyes today :) You explanation of the dump helped to see it.

Comment: I simplified my struct to just have the byte and the string, and it still is throwing the error using both 1 and 2 for the offset.

Comment: well I am running out of ideas: Have you tried  [FieldOffset(2)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=8)]
    public string Title; // or any sizeConst that works for you..

Comment: If I don't get an answer by tomorrow that actually tries to solve my problem using AnsiBStr I will just use that method and mark you the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you confused the declarations of "Active" and "TitleLength" which seems to be skipped completely..

Comment: Active is a single byte charater, doing a char or string would read in two bytes. Also for Title all strings are ANSI encoded which means there is a one byte length byte (TitleLength) followed by the string, doing MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr) should automatically read that byte and read in the correct number of characters in to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an IntPtr instead of a string, and then call [Marshall.PtrToStringAnsi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b620dhe.aspx)

You will need to retain the exact layout of the old code in order for this conversion to work. The binary is going to be stored in the format that it was last saved in, so you have to reproduce it exactly, even if that means using bytes and byte arrays everywhere.

If you want to use your new layout instead, you can create a version with the old layout, load them up copy values over to your new format and then save them back out with the new format. From then on you can load them up with your new layout instead. With that scenario your options are endless for your new format.

Comment: As per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c0157f5.aspx) MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr) does exactly what the old code is trying to do. it will read in one byte, use that as the length of the string in the following bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Pack = 1 with LayoutKind.Explicit
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack.aspx

Comment: I think this error occurs because all values are aligned to 4-byte boundaries. If you change offset of Title from 1 to 4 in your 2-field structure, code will run without exception. You can try to use LayoutKind.Sequential with Pack = 1 and set  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr,SizeConst= )] for each string; [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst= )] for arrays to solve your problem.